# Sum series product

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

in a probability computation problem on research, I am facing a conditional probability, which can be modeled with the following simplified formulation:

$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)}$, $a>0$, $b>0$

I have investigated this problem for a while and no conclusive result found. I would appreciate if you would please let me know a solution clue.

Comment: Is it with $0<a<1$ and $0<b<1$?

Comment: No, both $a > 0$ and $b > 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $a, b \not\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \ne b$, then
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)}
&= \frac{1}{a-b}\sum_{x=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{x-a} - \frac{1}{x-b}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{b-a}\sum_{x=0}^\infty\left[
\left(\frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x-a}\right) -
\left(\frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x-b}\right)
\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{b-a}\left[(\gamma+\psi(-a)) - (\gamma+\psi(-b))\right]\\
&= \frac{\psi(-a)-\psi(-b)}{b-a}
\end{align}
$$
where $\psi(z)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Comment: Do we have digamma function applied to negative values e.g., -a?

Comment: @PrinceofParse As long as $x$ is not an negative integer nor zero, $\psi(x)$ is defined.

Comment: so why we have digamma of -a there? why not to put a?

Comment: @PrinceofParse you are summing $\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)}$, not $\frac{1}{(x+a)(x+b)}$

Comment: Apologize for a repetitive question, then when we have ψ(-a) and $a > 0$, don't we apply ψ(x) on a negative value, and doesn't it result in an undefined situation?

Comment: @PrinceofParse The digamma function $\psi(z)$ is defined for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0, -1, -2, -3, \cdots \}$. As long as $a \not\in \mathbb{N}$, $\psi(-a)$ is fine.

Comment: But what about my case which $a \in N$ and a > 0?

Comment: @PrinceofParse In that case, your sum contain a term $\frac{1}{(a-a)(a-b)}$ at $x = a$ and become undefined.